# The Tao of Transistor Biasing

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, circuit-design

I *think* I understand the principle of transistor biasing but i'm a bit lost on forward vs reverse biasing.

Can an EE look at a schematic and tell the biasing of a transistor--reverse/forward?
Or is this something that must be calculated to understand how and where it's occurring?

Comment: *Can an EE look at a schematic and tell its biasing--reverse/forward?* Posess that skill some of do, yes. Wisely it must be used. Not for the ill-of-faith this skill is. Understanding of this skill you seek young Grasshopper ? Be read must be books on Analog design to explain, Biasing of devices.

Comment: Biasing of what? Diodes, transistors, opinions, ... You need to improve the question or it will probably be closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic principle is easy to describe:

- An npn transistor in common-emitter configuration needs a forward-biased B-E pn junction and a reverse-biased B-C pn junction.
- For realizing these requirements with one single supply voltage it is common practice to use a positive voltage (at least several volts)  between collector and common ground (VCE) and a resistive voltage divider producing the required B-E voltage of app. VBE=0.7 V.
- More than that, it is highly recommended not to ground the emitter but to use an emitter resistance RE (app. 10%...20% of the collector resistance RC). This resistor provides negative DC feedback and stabilizes the bias point against tolerances and temperature influences.